# Constructuing a 2D surface from a function that contains multiplication of dataframe elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 tables(DataFrames), each has 2 columns. Let's say `M1["a1","b1"]` and `M2["a2","b2"]`.
(M1 and M2 are actually refer to the same csv. I just describe them as two tables because of the function G below.)

I also have a function `G = a1*b1*a2*b2 + a1*b1`.
Just to make my question more clear, I would write function `G` as `G(n,m) = a1(n)*b1(n)*a2(m)*b2(m) + a1(n)*b1(n)` and would like to mention that (a1[n],b1[n]) always come in fixed pair, i.e., there is no (a1[3],b1[5]).

Later, I want to plot this function `G` with `n` corresponds with x-axis and `m` corresponds with y-axis.
The value of `G` itself will correspond with z-axis.
The final purpose is to find which `(a,b) pair` that gives the minimum value of `G`, if any.

How should I write function G in python?

Writing the following simply gives me error.

```
for n in a1,b1:
    for m in a2,b2:
        G = a1*b1*a2*b2 + a1*b1 #works, but the result consists only 1 column
        G[:,:] = a1[n]*b1[n]*a2[m]*b2[m] + a1[n]*b1[n] #error
        print(G)
```

I used simpler variable names above to simplify the post.
Here is my real code.

```
NMOS_gm_gmid = pandas.read_csv('NMOS_gm_gmid.csv', sep=',' , encoding='UTF-8')
NMOS_gm_gmid = NMOS_gm_gmid.apply(pandas.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
NMOS_ro_gmid = pandas.read_csv('NMOS_ro_gmid.csv', sep=',' , encoding='UTF-8')
NMOS_ro_gmid = NMOS_ro_gmid.apply(pandas.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

gm1 = NMOS_gm_gmid.iloc[:10,2] 
ro1 = 1 / NMOS_ro_gmid.iloc[:10,2] * 1e6

gm2 = NMOS_gm_gmid.iloc[:10,2]
ro2 = 1 / NMOS_ro_gmid.iloc[:10,2] * 1e6

Gm = gm1*ro1*gm2*ro2 + gm1*ro1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy broadcast here:

```
# M1, M2 from the same dataframe:
a1,b1,a2,b2 = df[['a1','b1','a2','b2']].to_numpy().T

G = (a1 * b1 + 1) * (a2*b2)[:,None]
```

Comment: there is this error:
`KeyError: "['a1' 'b1' 'a2' 'b2'] not in index"`

Comment: This comes from your question *Let's say M1["a1","b1"] and M2["a2","b2"]. (M1 and M2 are actually refer to the same csv)*. If you get a key error, then I'm not sure what you meant by that.

Comment: Hmm...M1 and M2 is the name of the table. a# and b# are the name of the columns. Sorry if I was not clear. I am new to this.

Comment: Yes, and I don't understand why you say *M1 and M2 refers to the same csv*. Anyway, split them `a1,b1 = M1[['a1','b1']].to_numpy().T` and same for `a2,b2`.

Comment: hmm...I have the same error: `KeyError: "['a1' 'b1'] not in index"`
I put my real code in my post, maybe you would like to take a look.

Comment: it turns out there are unwanted character in my column name. I posted the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65098822/deleting-unwanted-characters-in-the-column-names-in-python