# Deleting unwanted characters in the column names in python

Tags: python, pandas

There are unwanted character in my 1st column name.
These characters are not visible in excel, notepad, sublime.

I tried a tips from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831496/key-error-when-selecting-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-after-read-csv) to check the column names. Only by this way, the unwanted characters can be seen.

Is there any good solution for this?

```
M1
Out[347]: 
        ﻿a1        b1        a2        b2
0  0.238066  0.976816  0.238066  0.976816
1  0.373340  1.469728  0.373340  1.469728
2  0.968814  1.248595  0.968814  1.248595
3  0.886586  3.451292  0.886586  3.451292
4  0.244301  2.206757  0.244301  2.206757
5  0.389688  2.893761  0.389688  2.893761
6  0.704340  2.621483  0.704340  2.621483
7  0.301238  1.678316  0.301238  1.678316
8  0.375927  0.574135  0.375927  0.574135
9  0.065749  2.259736  0.065749  2.259736

print(M1.columns.tolist())
['\ufeffa1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2']

M1.columns = M1.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')

print(M1.columns.tolist())
['\ufeffa1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2']
```

Comment: Have you tried reading file with `utf-8-sig` encoding?

Comment: no option for `utf-8-sig` encoding in notepad. I tried to save it with UTF-8 and ANSI, but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Please use 'Some String'.encode('ascii', 'ignore') which gives
bytes and use decode to get string

Code:

```
lst = ['\ufeffa1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2']
print(lst)
newlst = [s.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8") for s in lst]

print(newlst)
```

Output:

```
['\ufeffa1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2']
['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2']
```

Comment: this deletes the unwanted character in the list. but how to correct the file?

Answer (score 0):

The character `\ufeef` (U+FEFF) is a [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which is a special character that informs the reader on the "endianness" of the encoding (little-endian vs big-endian). The BOM is optional for utf-8 and it's usually not written. You are probably reading a UTF-8 file with BOM using the default encoding, which is 'utf-8' (utf-8 without BOM). Try using 'utf-8-sig' (utf-8 with BOM).

```py
# You file is probably encoded with 'utf-8-sig'. 
# You are decoding it with encoding='utf-8' (the default).
# This is what happens:
'hi there'.encode('utf-8-sig').decode('utf-8')
Out[14]: '\ufeffhi there'

'hi there'.encode('utf-8-sig').decode('utf-8-sig')
Out[15]: 'hi there'
```

EDIT: "so what should I do with the file? changing encoding does not solve the issue."

You could open notepad++, then Format -> Convert to UTF-8. Or in Python:

```py
with open(input_path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as fin:
    text = fin.read()
with open(output_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    fout.write(text)
```

This will remove the BOM.

Comment: sorry, so what should I do with the file? changing encoding does not solve the issue.

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong. I edited my answer to explain how you can remove the BOM. I didn't test the code. Let me know if it runs without errors.

Comment: @Codelearner777 I hate to write this, but when some people spend their time to help you for free, the least you can do is to reply / upvote / accept one of the answers. If my answer didn't solve your problem, I'd like to know it.

Answer (score 0):

This is Encoding problem.

```python
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3,10,16).reshape(4,4), columns=['\ufeffa1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2'])
   ...: df.head()
Out[3]: 
   ﻿a1  b1  a2  b2
0    7   7   9   6
1    5   9   6   7
2    4   8   4   3
3    6   9   8   7

In [4]: df.columns
Out[4]: Index(['﻿a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2'], dtype='object')

In [5]: df.columns.to_list()
Out[5]: ['\ufeffa1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2']

In [6]: df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns).apply(lambda x:x.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8-sig'))

In [7]: df.columns
Out[7]: Index(['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2'], dtype='object')

In [8]: df.columns.to_list()
Out[8]: ['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2']
```